# How to know the ip addresses under a router

Tags: networking, ip, penetration-testing

I'm trying to understand if there are others computer into a unknown network.(i'm doing a penetetration testing in a private network)
After a nmap scanning and a Wireshark analysis i found the router candidate that has the ip addresses 192.168.193.85 and i want to know the list of all the ip addresses / machines under this subnet.
How can i know it ?

Thanks

Marco

Comment: This is class C network which means that there are only 254 possible hosts. Try maybe pinging each of them?

Comment: Hi @gudok , i made the ping for all the range 192.168.193.0/24 and i found 5 hosts alive. Now the wireshark analysis reveal that there are icmp6 router advertisement comes from the ip 192.168.193.85 or something other machine under his scope. My objective is to find a web server under that scope, but i still don't know how to catch him.

Comment: @gudok, classful networking has been dead for over 20 years! Without a network mask, you have no way of knowing how many addresses there are. If the network is `192.168.192.0/23`, there could be twice as many addresses as you assume, or if it is `192.168.193.64/26` there could only be a quarter of the addresses you assume. There are just too many combinations, and you need the mask to know for sure.

Comment: Ok i solved, i also know the subnet and the router address, so i added a new route from the sniffed ip's via router 192.168.193.85 like this: ip route add 10.86.74.0/24 via 192.168.193.85

Answer (score 1):

Hi as you only want to locate the webserver in the subnet you can basically use the nmap command for the same

```
nmap 192.168.193.0/24 --open -p80,443
```

i am using 80,443 port which are basically used for web servers you can add other ports if you know what kind of the services they use.